# Redirecting URL to different domain:port locally

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-server-2016, port-forwarding

I hope this question is appropriate to serverfault. Otherwise please let me know where else is best.

**Situation:**
Server A is used for some automation which access a webserver on server B.
The webserver domain is B.int.ca and the website is accessible through port 5000.
Server A and Server B are in different zones which means in order for server A to access the website on server B, it has to go through the NAT which is AtoB.int.ca on port 7000

So far so good all works well.

**The problem:** No matter how the website was built, when we want to download a file when accessed from AtoB NAT on server A, the file link will show as B.int.ca:5000/somefile.txt instead of AtoB.int.ca:7000/somefile.txt. Therefore it cannot be downloaded.

Would there be some way to create a port forwarding on server A which would redirect every request made locally to B.int.ca:5000 redirected to AtoB.int.ca:7000 ?

**Restrictions:** I definitely cannot change anything on the NAT nor on the website not on Server B.
I only have freedom of change on server A.
I cannot change my automation code, it can only click on the link to download the file.

**What I tried:** I realize that the hosts file does not work with ports and only hostname so that didn't work for me.
Then I got the impression netsh portproxy could work but I guess it won't since it would only redirect connection to Server A to another place.

Is there any way out of this?

Comment: Which network protocol is used to download a file? If that's HTTP(S), maybe, easier to just deploy a reverse proxy on a port 5000, which will just proxy request to port 7000?

Comment: That's an interesting idea and yes it is http., I'll look into this